# Problems on finite collection of non-empty subsets of a universe

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

### Question

> Suppose $(S_{1}, S_{2},...,S_{m})$ is a finite collection of non-empty subsets of a universe U. Note that the sets in this collection need not be distinct. Consider the following basic step to be performed on this sequence. While there exist sets $S_{i}$ and $S_{j}$ in the sequence, neither of which is a subset of the other, delete them from the sequence, and

a. If $S_{i}\cap S_{j}\neq \emptyset $, then add the sets $S_{i}\cup S_{j}$ and $S_{i}\cap S_{j}$ to the sequence;

b. If $S_{i}\cap S_{j} = \emptyset$, then add only the set $S_{i}\cup S_{j}$ to the sequence.

> In each step, we delete two sets from the sequence and add at most two sets to the sequence. Also, note that empty sets are never added to the sequence. Which of the following statements is **TRUE**?

1. The size of the smallest set in the sequence decreases in every step.
2. The size of the largest set in the sequence increases in every step.
3. The process always terminates.
4. The process terminates if $U$ is finite but might not if $U$ is infinite.
5. There is a finite collection of subsets of a finite universe $U$ and a choice
   of $S_{i}$ and $S_{j}$ in each step such that the process does not terminate.

### My Attempt

**case**$1$

if $S_{i} \subseteq S_{j}$

then the sequence will be like $S_{1}\,\,S_{2}\,\,S_{3}\,\,S_{4}\,\,\cdot\,\,\cdot\,$ will go on

Example-:
$S_{1}$=$\left \{1,2,3 \right \}\,\,S_{2}=\left \{1,2,3,4 \right \}\,\,S_{3}=\left \{1,2,3,4,5 \right \}\,\,\,\,\cdot\,\cdot\,\cdot\,\cdot$

**Case** $2_{a}$

if $S_{i}$ and $S_{j}$ are not the  subset of each other then

Example-:
$S_{1}$=$\left \{1,2,3 \right \}\,\,S_{2}=\left \{3,4,5 \right \}\,\,S_{3}=\left \{4,5,6,7 \right \}\,\,\,\,\cdot\,\cdot\,\cdot\,\cdot$

then the sequence will be like $S_{1}\,\,S_{2}$,

Hold on , $S_{1}\,\nsubseteq\,S_{2}$$\Rightarrow$Remove $S_{1}\,\,S_{2}$,
$\Rightarrow$Add $S_{1}\,\cup \,S_{2}$ and add$S_{1}\,\cap \,S_{2}$

Let $S_{x}=S_{1}\,\cup \,S_{2}$

Let $S_{y}=S_{1}\,\cap \,S_{2}$

Now my Sequence is

$S_{x}\,\,S_{y}\,\,\cdot\,\,\cdot\,$

Considering case 2$_{b}$ in the same way,i think that the sequence is nothing but $Power set$ of  $\left \{1,2,3,\,\cdot\,\,\cdot\,\,m\right \}$

Leading me to choose option$4$

i.e

> The process terminates if U is finite but might not if U is infinite.

Am i going Right?

Please help me out

Comment: When you say neither of which is a subset of the other, do you mean strictly a subset of, or just subset? i.e. do we consider $A $ to be a subset of itself?

Comment: @RSerrao:I don't know what they try to mean!Actually it is a research entrance examination Question ,what i think is :yes! $A$ can be subset of itself !

Comment: I'm afraid I can't make any sense of your cases. This is an interesting question! It's easy to disprove 1 and 2 (simultaneously) with an example where $m=2.$ It seems clear that the process must terminate for finite $U,$ but I think it may terminate for *any* $U$. Have you tried proving termination by induction on $m$?

Comment: @CameronBuie sir : no i haven't tried by induction ! i am trying it by hit and trial ! need some guidance :)

Comment: @CameronBuie sir,  sad part is that i don't know the exact key !